# XGBOOST down graded and KeyError: 'num_parallel_tree'

Tags: python, xgboost

I down graded my xgboost version from 1.7.3 to 1.4.2 and when I try to fit dataset I take KeyError: 'num_parallel_tree' error. How can I solve this?

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible example